# Define and check variable in if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am wanting to see if there is a simplified way of doing an `if` statement that is checking multiple conditions, where it uses data from the same function.

```
if($class->function($id) && $class->function($id)['key'] > 0)
{ 
    //Do something...
}
```

The issue here is we're making 2 database calls that retrieve the same data. One obvious solution is doing the following:

```
$classVariable = $class->function($id);
if($classVariable && $classVariable['key'] > 0)
{
    //Do something...
}
```

My question specifically is, can I achieve the same effect all inside the `if` statement? For example(this will not work):

```
if($classVariable = $class->function($id) && $classVariable['key'] > 0
{
    //Do something...
}
```

Is this possible, and is there a preferred way of doing this? It seems to me that defining and using it in the same statement would be cleaner code...

Comment: Use `()` around the assignment and it will work just fine.

Comment: It should be noted, that while you *can* do it this way, it isn't the recommended way. You should declare the variable before the if statement. But, it's your code & you're welcome to do it however you'd like :)

Comment: That works. Does anybody know if there is a preference between defining it first then doing the `if` statement, or defining it inside the `if` statement?

Edit: Kenyon posted while I was asking. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Kenyon - Is there any reasoning as to why that is the recommended way?

Comment: @MarkGeorge Readability and cleanliness.

Comment: @MarkGeorge, Charlotte Dunois is right

Comment: @CharlotteDunois and *"cleanliness is next to Godliness"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Niet said, using parentheses () around the $classVariable assignment and things should work.

(I just wanted to post this as an answer rather than a comment so the question gets resolved, sorry Niet)

Edited by OP to show answer in code...

```
if(($classVariable = $class->function($id)) && $classVariable['key'] > 0)
{
    //Do something...
}
```

Comment: ham out your answer a bit more by including what it looks like with the parenthesis added.

Comment: @pancho018 - I added it in

Comment: another 34 rep to go and you'll be able to comment too ;-) just like Niet. Writing good/better answers attracts (positive) votes, btw. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Got it! Thanks, have always just looked at StackExchange but never answered!